# Is there a move that engages almost all muscles in the body to be able to attack with the most energy?

Tags: attack

I was looking for a martial arts move that uses most of your body energy to knock down your enemy or even break a wall with it; I have heard that if you use only a few muscles of your body to attack, you use less energy therefore less force, but if you use almost all of your muscles in one move you will be able to generate much more force.

Is there any move that engages almost all of your muscles to generate the most force?

Comment: As per https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/are-there-any-exercise-that-engage-almost-all-of-your-muscles, engaging all of your muscles would result in you locking up since they operate in opposition. Kind of like how having 100% of your brain active is essentially a really horrible seizure...

Comment: @Sean Duggan edited the question.

Comment: Ditto Sean Duggan's comment. Look up antagonistic muscle response. There are few muscles that actually are involved in the motion itself. The rest are there to stabilize your skeletal system. Your spine is flexible and has many joints (vertebrae), so you need "core" muscles around your torso to stabilize it, for example. If you don't do that, the force of the push will not be supported. Look into power lifting and Olympic lifts to work on full body explosive strength. Lots of other exercises as well, like sled, truck tires, giant rope, bungee cords, etc.

Comment: Aside from my slightly snarky comment above, I think one also has the answer that most martial arts moves try to use as many muscles of the human body at once. Even the bog-standard reverse punch involves using the muscles of the legs, torso, and arms to drive the punch forward. Ditto with the kicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for *chapéu de couro* in Capoeira. It's a Roundhouse Kick from sitting position. I'll try to describe it, but I'll link you a video as well.

You start in a position with 1 foot on the ground, your other leg stretch leaning on the heel. The side of the leg that is stretched has your hand on the ground next to your body.
From there you push your body up with the foot that's on the ground and rotate, leaning on your hand, kick your leg towards the side.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KDyNbFgqEI

This move has proven to be the most powerful kick by 2 Martial Arts Science researchers.
It uses your entire kinetic energy to perform a kick, resulting in a lot of power and not only a hard impact, but also a hard pushthrough.

Comment: I saw a video where this kick [lost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gnu94B6Edrs) to a Taekwondo kick.

Comment: Yes, the Taekwon Do kick produced the most power, but the ratio of power to velocity was a lot higher in Capoeira. Which can mean a couple of things. The Taekwon Do fighter was most likely physically fitter, but Capoeira's kick was a lot more effective, because it uses the entire kinetic energy. It also had a more centered impact which leads to a lot more damage done even at less force applied.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The Taekwondo kick was faster, the Capoeira kick had more weight behind it. that's it. For some reason the researchers in the show praised the Caporira kick for putting more weight  behind the kick instead of speed, bur combat-wise, it makes no sense. I don't know what you talking about when saying:  "The Taekwon Do fighter was most likely physically fitter", "it uses the entire kinetic energy" ,"also had a more centered impact".

Comment: Probably doesn't help that Lateef Crowder is a big muscular guy, so he was naturally hitting with more force.

Comment: Alaychem, even if it makes no sense combat wise, because of the amount of time required to set it up, it doesn't take away the fact that the impact is massive. If you don't know what kinetic energy is, you should probably look it up. It's a very important component in the vast majority of martial arts. The impact being more centred comes from the driving force. When you push an object into an other object at a more constant speed, it's likely to deal more centred damage. Whereas pushing an object into another object really fast and hard divides the damage more.

Comment: This basically means that when the damage is more centred, it deals more damage to a specific area. Whereas damages that gets divided deals damage to a bigger area, but less overall damage. The use of kinetic energy from the capoeira kick causes the driving force to be more constant. The weight is driven into the dummy and keeps going longer. The Taekwondo kick hits the dummy far shorter, resulting in quick damage to a wider area, but overall less weight is pressed into the dummy.

Comment: Let's say they were to use both of these kicks on a human being of identical structural integrity, the capoeira kick would leave the human being incapacitated. Whereas the taekwondo kick would leave a big bruise instead.

Comment: @Sjana I konw what kinetic energy is, yet I disagree with everything you wrote. Why do think that the Capoeira kick had more kinetic energy? the measurement's in the show showed otherwise, and why do you think that  the Capoeira kick was more centered? both kicks hit with the same part of the leg.

Comment: @AlaychemgoestoCodidact That takes the post into an entirely different direction, namely physics, biology and science. That is not the topic of the question and I don't have enough character in a comment section to explain how it works to you.

Answer (score 1):

Craig Pumphrey's [brick breaking ram technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFeDE5VsQsQ) is very impressive, and definitely utilize many muscles to create impact.
Also, it can be used to break a wall.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, maneuvers that require a switch in stance can generate a lot of energy by utilizing the rotational muscles in the legs and core. Leading a switch maneuver in to an attack like a straight punch, cross, elbow, hook or a round house kick will further generate more energy.

I have spent a lot of time training the concept and I've arrived at a few fundamental conclusions. There is a ratio of energy input into muscles which corresponds to the size and function of the muscle. You can train the maneuver via mediation whereby you focus your muscles (flex) to the point of tension just before motion is generated.

If you hold your limbs in the center of their range of motion and slowly increase the amount of tension being applied, it will train the first few stages (for lack of a better term) of the muscle's activation, which starts off as a sugar being burned.

Muscles doing what muscles do starts genetically with the warping of a DNA strand which binds chemicals and forces molecules closer together.

[image: A detailed structure of striated muscle]

This image is the 3rd stage in a muscle's contraction in which the bio-chemical processes have already happened and the cellular structure of the muscle is starting to contract.

Now about the misconception of power; training in this manner via mediation greatly increases reaction speed. Many people misconstrue weight and mass with power, but "power", as it were, is mass moving at a velocity. Literally a fractional e=mc2 equation (energy = mass x the speed of light squared).

I like to think about it like DragonBall. Carry weight constantly like a backpack full of books; this will train your body to be adaptive to external pressures being applied and strengthen the legs and core in which most internal energy is generated and channelled.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ON1Pwn_p8s

Meditation couldn't be more important; a well trained mediation skill will grant access to the body's "Operation System", which in turn will allow you to utilize all of the muscles in your body to preform tasks more efficiently.

Lastly, the warning no one ever gives; training can cause serious injury, so proceed with caution and care.

Comment: That's a lot of information, but I'm not certain how much of it really answers the question.